# VBA - goto excel error message in error handling if

Tags: vba

I wanted to write the error handling for vba, which after directing to the error handling will first check for a specific error and if there is no match, it will show the error message as according to Excel.

Here is my code:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandl

ErrorHandl:
If Err.Number = 13 Then
  MsgBox "Do that …", vbCritical
  Exit Sub
Else
??????
```

What could I write in the place of questions marks, so that if error number is different than 13 then, excel will show me the other error that is currently occurring?

Comment: You could use a Message Box to show `Err.Description`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote now is error number specific. You could also write a general error handler

```
Sub test()
On error GoTo Errorhandler

 '''
 'Code
 '''

Exit Sub
Errorhandler:
MSgbox "Warning: fatal error occured." & vbCr & vbCr "Error message:" & vbCr & Err.Description, vbcritical, "Error"
End Sub
```

This will, regardless of which error occured, display a message box warning the user of a fatal error followed by the error message as displayed in VBE.

Of course, you could also specify the error code instead of making it general

Comment: The Exit sub before Errorhandler was the bull's eye for me. Thanks

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible way to get custom errors with `Select Case:`. If the error is number 11 (Division by 0), then it gives a customized `MsgBox`. Othewise it gives a standard one with the `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`, based on the current language of the system (Mine is German):

[image]

The code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    On Error GoTo TestMe_Error

    Debug.Print 5 / 0

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

TestMe_Error:

    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 11:
        MsgBox "Division by null is not allowed on this planet!"
    Case Else:
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure TestMe."
    End Select

End Sub
```

And if you need a multipurpose Error-Handler, this is the code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    On Error GoTo TestMe_Error

    Debug.Print 5 / 0

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

TestMe_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure TestMe."

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting error 0. I am using if loop and else ifs instead of 'Case is'. Then I get the MsgBox as you typed and gives Error(0).

Comment: @Dozens - error number 0 means no error. Did you copy+paste my solution or you wrote something else? What exactly?

Comment: The idea of the error handler is to write all your code in the place `Debug.Print 5 / 0` of the code above.

Comment: the thing was that there was missing 'Exit sub' before Erroe handler

Comment: @Dozens - `Exit Sub` was in both the answers.

Comment: Yes, Now I see. But I have not seen it at the time.